# best books, lecture notes, for studying pullback rings

Tags: reference-request, commutative-algebra, book-recommendation, limits-colimits

> Does anyone have suggestions for *books*, or *lecture notes*, (or videos) for studying pullback rings?

I know definition;

[image]

and a few facts about it (for example when it is Noetherian). Now I want to start for learning it. I'm not good at *category theory*, so please consider this in your answer.  I've read *Bruns-Herzog*'s book an I'm familiar with homological algebra.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You want a whole book on pullbacks of rings?

Comment: No. but a section that have an easy and basic approach.

Comment: Computing limits of rings is straightforward, since it's just the limit of the underlying sets equipped with a ring structure. Colimits are more subtle. Do you understand how to compute pullbacks of diagrams of sets?

Comment: Qiaochu Yuan! thank you for good question that helped me to edit...